# I want to add dropdown that comes from custom table in typo3 solr facets

Tags: solr, typo3

I have indexed page correctly and solr is working, but I want to insert facets.

I have write below typoscript for adding contain of table tx_srcdataprovider_domain_model_tag, it added in index queue but not indexed properly.

How do I show all tag fields in dropdown in facets?

Please give me some example to add facets in typo3 solr.

Thanks in advance

```
tx_srcdataprovider_domain_model_tag = 1
tx_srcdataprovider_domain_model_tag {

   table = tx_srcdataprovider_domain_model_tag
   fields {
      tag = tag                 
      // the special SOLR_CONTENT content object cleans HTML and RTE     fields
    content = SOLR_CONTENT
    content {
            field = description
    }

    // the special SOLR_RELATION content object resolves relations
    category_stringM = SOLR_RELATION
    category_stringM {
        localField = category
        multiValue = 1
    }

    // build the URL through typolink, make sure to use returnLast = url
    url = TEXT
    url {
        typolink.parameter = 1
        typolink.additionalParams = &tx_srcdataprovider_domain_model_tag[item]={field:uid}
        typolink.additionalParams.insertData = 1
        typolink.returnLast = url
        typolink.useCacheHash = 1
    }

    // the special SOLR_MULTIVALUE content object allows to index multivalue fields
    keywords = SOLR_MULTIVALUE
    keywords {
        field = keywords
    }
    tag_stringS  = tag
}
```

Comment: Please clean up your question and improve structure. Did you consult the faceting documentation of EXT:solr? https://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-solr/wiki/Tx_solrsearch#facetingfacetsfacetName-single-facet-configuration

Comment: I want to render values of table field as selectbox in facets. I have read documents of facets but not found how to do this.